# Dompdf align two text block

Tags: css, pdf, dompdf

I'd like to align two p blocks in the same lane; I'm using barrydompdf and I can't use the table formatting because I have  text block of more than 2000 characters length.

That's the best I could do so far:

[image: First part]

but you see, the second block starts right after the first:

[image]

This is the css

```
.pblock{
             border:0.3px solid black;
             margin-left:2px;
             width:702px;

      }
.pblock .left{
            float: left;
            width : 50%;
            height: 100%;

        }
.pblock .right{

    float: right;

            width : 50%;
            display: inline-block;




        }
.left p{
    padding: 10px;
}
.right p{
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left:25px;
}
```

and that's the html

```
<div class="pblock">

                        <div class="left">
                                <p align="justify">
                                        {!! $data->forza !!}
                                    </p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="right">
                                <p align="justify">
                                        {!! $data->miglioramento !!}
                                    </p>
                        </div>


                    </div>
```

Comment: With such a large block of text, is the content of the first block being paged? If so Dompdf (currently at 0.8.4) won't work for you because Dompdf renders content as it's encountered. So if you have a floated block that breaks to the next page then any following content will start rendering on that page).

Comment: Thank you for your replay: that's exactly what happens, the content starts rendering from the other page...